# Centos JBOSS deploy war file fail, cannot load the persistence.xml. Working on Windows 7 but not centos

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, war, persistence.xml

i have spent two days still can't solve the problem.

My problem is that I　have a war file using JPA and Hibernate. When i deploy on windows JBOSS AS 7.1.1  it works prefect. However, when i deployed it on Centos 5.8 JBOSS AS 7.1.1 it throws exception. The root cause is the very common:
     **Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named XX**

I have no idea why it works differently in two OS. I am having JDK7 update 21 on both machines.

Development Machine: Windows 7(64bit), Eclipse IDE, JDK7_21
Deployment Machine: Centos 5.8(64bit),

I have try using

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Enumeration<URL> resources1 = loader.getResources("/META-INF/persistence.xml");
URL seurl = resources1.nextElement();
```

However, this only works on Windows 7, on Centos it didn't get the persistence.xml and throws NOSuchElement Exception when calling **.nextElement()**. I have place the META-INF folder as resoures and when deployed it is placed in this location xx.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml.

Can someone help me to find out what is going wrong? Many thanks.

I would like to post the exception thrown as well:

```
19:26:30,685 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/bms]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hrBean': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named shundebuspersistenceunit
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:343) [spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21] 

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named shundebuspersistenceunit
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:531) [spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:497) [spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) [spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:631) [spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:340) [spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            ... 21 more 

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named shundebuspersistenceunit
            at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69) [hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:94) [spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310) [spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
            ... 34 more
```

Comment: ALso try in ubunu got the same error. so must be something wrong. and i couldn't find it..

Answer (score 0):

OK.. I have solved my own problem and it is a silly stupid answer.

Windows can understand and treat Capital Letters, so **Persistence.xml** is equivalent to **persistence.xml**. While in UNIX/Linux are not.

So the answer is change the file name from **Persistence.xml** to **persistence.xml**.

T_T